# Change search bar color when active in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uisearchbar

So I'm using a basic search bar right now. It looks like this

[image]

And when it comes active it looks like this

[image]

So my question is how can I have the "active" search bar/navbar to also be a green color. But return to the default when it's not active. I've done some research. But nothing has sparked the solution yet. Any ideas? I'm working in Swift, by the way.

Comment: Have you tried out the functions from [UISearchBarDelegate?](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html). Changing UISearchBars `barTintColor` in the correspondent functions should do the job.

Comment: I have, but it changes the not active bar as well @iLenwe

Comment: You could, for example, use `func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool` to change the navbar and the searchbars `barTintColor`to green and something like `func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) { 
        searchbar.barTintColor = nil navbar.barTintColor = nil
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }`to change the `barTintColor` back to grey. So whenever the user taps into the searchfield, the Search- and NavBar will be green and when the user presses the search button, the colors will change back to the default color.